# GWT Java - set font style

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I want to set the label style depending on certain input. I have found how to set the colour, font weight, font style, font size and indent. However, I can not find how to set the font family to, e.g., "Arial".

```
lblTaskName.getElement().getStyle().setColor("Navy");
lblTaskName.getElement().getStyle().setFontWeight(FontWeight.BOLD);
lblTaskName.getElement().getStyle().setFontStyle(FontStyle.ITALIC);
lblTaskName.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(14.0, Unit.PT);
lblTaskName.getElement().getStyle().setTextIndent(15.0, Unit.PT);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen issue with`Widget#getElement()#setAttribute()` in IE. 
The better way is:

```
myWidget.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("fontFamily", "Arial");
```

I've never tried font-family in this way. The general rule for `getStyle().setProperty('camelCase','value')`

`camel-case` becomes -> `camelCase`.

Comment: Thanks Jama this works a treat. So here is another challenge to get my text looking really good. When a line of indented text is longer than the widget it wraps around and resumes at the start of the widget container instead of directly under the indented text. Is it possible to align the text at the indented level (e.g., 18 px in from the left edge)? For this I would need to set left padding instead of indent? Regards, Glyn.

Comment: An the solution to aligning the left side of the text is to set padding like so: //Set the indent level.
     int indentLevel = Integer.parseInt(ymAwardDetails.getAdIndentLevel());
     int indent = indentLevel * 18;
     lblTaskName.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("padding", "0px"+" "+"0px"+" "+"0px"+" "+indent+"px");. From experimenting I found that the order is top, right, bottom, left. I hope this helps someone else. Regards, Glyn. @Andrei

Comment: Hi @Glyn, sorry I didn't have a chance to read through your comment and question... but I'm glad that you found the solution. If you have a a unrelated question to the answer please ask it as a new question instead of asking it in a comment. If you do so, more guys will see the question and you will get the answer faster. :) Hope this helps..

Comment: Hi Jama, No worries. This was more of a challenge I set myself. I found the basics on this however nothing on setting the second parameter as a variable so I played with it and found the solution. It was guess work on my part that adding '+"px"' to the variable would work. I just hope this helps others who want to format their output depending on input parameters. Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing so many properties, I would recommend defining a class in your CSS and applying this class to the label.

```
myWidget.addStyleName("label");
```

It's a much cleaner approach than hardcoding all values in your code. For example, you can add rules to your CSS file to adjust these properties based on a screen size, and you won't have to touch your code.

Comment: I agree that CSS is a much cleaner approach. However, with each text line I read in I also read the formatting requirements (e.g., heading level, indent amount). So is it possible to do something like this "//Set the indent level.
    int indentLevel = Integer.parseInt(ymAwardDetails.getAdIndentLevel());
    int indent = indentLevel * 18;
    lblTaskName.getElement().getStyle().setTextIndent(indent, Unit.PT);" in CSS? Regards, Glyn